# DataTable.Merge not merging

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm trying to merge two `.NET` `DataTables`

```
DataTable dtCalls = new DataTable();
dtCalls.Columns.Add("EmpID",typeof(string));
dtCalls.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));
dtCalls.Columns.Add("Calls",typeof(int));

DataTable dtPages = new DataTable();
dtPages.Columns.Add("EmpID",typeof(string));
dtPages.Columns.Add("Date",typeof(DateTime));
dtPages.Columns.Add("Orders",typeof(int));

SqlCommand commRetrieveCalls = new SqlCommand(strRetrieveCalls,conn);
SqlDataAdapter adpRetrieveCalls = new SqlDataAdapter(commRetrieveCalls);
DataSet dsRetrieveCalls = new DataSet();
adpRetrieveCalls.Fill(dsRetrieveCalls);
DataTable dtRetrieveCalls = dsRetrieveCalls.Tables[0];

foreach(DataRow dr in dtRetrieveCalls.Rows) {
    dtCalls.Rows.Add(dr[0].ToString(),DateTime.Parse(dr[1].ToString()),Convert.ToInt32(dr[2].ToString()));
}

SqlCommand commRetrieveOrders = new SqlCommand(strRetrievePages,conn);
SqlDataAdapter adpRetrieveOrders = new SqlDataAdapter(commRetrieveOrders);
DataSet dsRetrieveOrders = new DataSet();
adpRetrieveOrders.Fill(dsRetrieveOrders);
DataTable dtRetrieveOrders = dsRetrieveOrders.Tables[0];

foreach(DataRow drOrder in dtRetrieveOrders.Rows) {
    dtPages.Rows.Add(drOrder[0].ToString(),DateTime.Parse(drOrder[1].ToString()),Convert.ToInt32(drOrder[2].ToString()));
}
```

The result, unfortunately is one table with `null` fields for each respective table's lacking column.

Comment: Where's the call to `Merge`?

Comment: dtCalls.Merge(dtPages,false,MissingSchemaAction.Add);

Comment: Does `dtCalls` end up with a row count equal to the row count of `dtCalls` plus the row count of `dtPages`?  Does it also end up with a new column named "Orders"?

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you haven't established primary keys for the tables, so `Merge` doesn't know how to merge the rows for the same employee (and date?) into a single row.  The result is likely that you end up with a union of the two tables.  Try setting the primary key in each table via something like `dtCalls.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtCalls.Columns[0], dtCalls.Columns[1] };` (assuming `Date` is part of the PK here).  Do the same for `dtPages`, then try your merge again.

Comment: Yes, it does contain the correct number of rows. Just a new Column with nulls in it, and conversely Rows with non null Orders have null Calls

Comment: Works.  BTW, any way to show null as zero?

Comment: Not sure how to replace nulls with zero in an elegant way.  There might be an event that you could handle as the merge is taking place, but I'm not sure if that's the case or not.  Worst case, I guess, is to just iterate through all rows after the merge is complete, checking each column for null and setting it zero if it is.  Btw, I've added an answer with the fix.  Please accept it to close out the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you haven't established primary keys for the tables, so Merge doesn't know how to merge the rows for the same employee (and date?) into a single row. The result is likely that you end up with a union of the two tables. Try setting the primary key in each table via something like `dtCalls.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dtCalls.Columns[0], dtCalls.Columns[1] };` (assuming Date is part of the PK here). Do the same for dtPages, then try your merge again.