# How to merge multiple DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable

When I want to join two tables it goes down one row. How can I solve this?

```
public DataTable MergeTables()
{
    var dataTable1 = new DataTable();
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Id");
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Name");
    dataTable1.Columns.Add("Surname");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("1", "Mike", "Tyson");
    dataTable1.Rows.Add("2", "John", "Wick");

    var dataTable2 = new DataTable();
    dataTable2.Columns.Add("Country");
    dataTable2.Columns.Add("Age");
    dataTable2.Rows.Add("America", "35");
    dataTable2.Rows.Add("Brasil", "50");

    dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2);
    return dataTable1;
}
```

[image: Output:]

Comment: Can you please provide a [mre]. The provided code throws an exception about columns/data mismatch and provided expected/output does not match columns/values from the code.

Comment: Sorry sir, I updated the question, can you look at the picture?

Comment: And what is expected?

Comment: What do you expect? What have you done to solve it? There are plenty of Stackoverflow threads on merge issues. [This one is possibly relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40267845/463206). And the web generally on C# merging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Merge` requires primary key to match the records:

```cs
var dataTable1 = new DataTable();
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Id");
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Name");
dataTable1.Columns.Add("Surname");
dataTable1.PrimaryKey = new [] { dataTable1.Columns["Id"] }; // set PK

dataTable1.Rows.Add("1", "Mike", "Tyson");
dataTable1.Rows.Add("2", "John", "Wick");

var dataTable2 = new DataTable();
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Id"); // add PK column
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Country");
dataTable2.Columns.Add("Age");
dataTable2.PrimaryKey = new [] { dataTable2.Columns["Id"] }; // set PK

dataTable2.Rows.Add("1", "America", "35"); // add PK value
dataTable2.Rows.Add("2", "Brasil", "50"); // add PK value

dataTable1.Merge(dataTable2);
```